# Javascript array/object/hash table to track cart availability

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is possible but it seems there must be a simpler way to do this. I currently have a shopping cart for a t-shirt store. Each t-shirt has 3 drop down boxes to select prior to purchase:

Style:

- American Apparel
- Gildan

Size:

- S
- M
- L
- XL

Colour:

- Blue
- Black
- White
- Grey

Not every style is available in every size and colour combination but apart from how the cart is laid out on the page, there is no set way for the user to select style first, then size without forcing it which will be a barrier to making a sale.

Right now, when the user selects anything from any of the drop down boxes, an ajax call is made to the server to calculate what the other drop down boxes should contain, for example if the user selects Size (L) first, the colour may change to just Blue and Black as White and Grey are not available in Large, but worse than that White may be available but only in Gildan style.

Anyway, the ajax call has latency and can be especially slow on mobile devices with a spotty data connection. Is there a way I can achieve this with Javascript instead. I know all the combinations prior to rendering the page, and I can set up an array but get lost due to having more than two drop down boxes and end up with this ugly mess, and even then I don't know how to do the actual function which changes the boxes because multiple boxes may be selected:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var styles = { aa: 'American Apparel', gi: 'Gildan' };
        var sizes = { s: 'Small', m: 'Medium', l: 'Large' };
        var colours = { blue: 'Blue', black: 'Black', white: 'White', grey: 'Grey' };

        var availability = {
            aa: { size: ['s', 'm', 'l'], colour: ['blue', 'black', 'white', 'grey'] },
            gi: { size: ['s', 'm'], colour: ['blue', 'black', 'white', 'grey'] },
            s: { style: ['aa', 'gi'], colour: ['blue', 'black', 'white'] },
            m: { style: ['aa', 'gi'], colour: ['black', 'white', 'grey'] },
            l: { style: ['aa'], colour: ['blue', 'black', 'white', 'grey'] },
            blue: { style: ['aa', 'gi'], size: ['s', 'l'] },
            black: { style: ['aa', 'gi'], size: ['s', 'm', 'l'] },
            white: { style: ['aa', 'gi'], size: ['s', 'm', 'l'] },
            grey: { style: ['aa', 'gi'], size: ['m', 'l'] }
        };

        $(function()
        {
            addOptions('style', styles);
            addOptions('size', sizes);
            addOptions('colour', colours);
        });

        function addOptions(name, data)
        {
            $('select[name="' + name + '"]').empty();

            $.each(data, function(value, description)
            {
                $('select[name="' + name + '"]').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + description + '</option>');
            });
        }

        function updateOptions(select)
        {
            // Work out what has changed, and update select boxes?
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="style" onchange="updateOptions(this);"></select>
    <select name="size" onchange="updateOptions(this);"></select>
    <select name="colour" onchange="updateOptions(this);"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this with a smarter function and/or hash table? These may not be the only three options, for example the store has pillows as well which have style, material, thread count and colour. Each set of options is unique to the product, but I know what they are prior to the page being rendered.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Assuming you only have a few options for each dropdown, it should be plenty sufficient to just keep a JS array of every possible combination, and loop through it when any dropdown selection is made (e.g. they select Black, just iterate the entire array finding any combinations that have colour of Black, and add the found combination's brand and size to a temporary array (or object, so duplicates aren't repeated) to update the dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to structure your data is with a multi-dimensional array (one dimension for each property) in which the values are true or false. I modeled it with that idea in mind, but with associative arrays (aka objects in JavaScript).

Data:

```
var availability = {
  'American Apparel' : {
    'S' : {
      'black' : true,
      'green' : true
    },
    'M' : {
      'black' : true,
      'white' : true
    }
  },
  'Gildan' : {
    'M' : {
      'black' : true
    },
    'XL' : {
      'black' : true,
      'white' : true,
      'green' : true
    }
  }
};
```

Now all you need is a function to return the possible options when some are selected. The first draft is below, but i'm sure it can be improved heavily. If a property is set, pass the value to the function, otherwise pass undefined. The function returns an object with 3 arrays indicating the valid options for the user's selection. Usage example at the end..

```
function pushIfNotIn(arr, item) {
  if (arr.indexOf(item) === -1) arr.push(item);
}

function getAvailability(styleValue, sizeValue, colorValue) {
  var av = {
    style : [],
    size : [],
    color : []
  };

  for (var style in availability) {
    if (styleValue === undefined || styleValue === style) {
      for (var size in availability[style]) {
        if (sizeValue === undefined || sizeValue === size) {
          for (var color in availability[style][size]) {
            if (colorValue === undefined || colorValue === color) {
              if (availability[style][size][color]) {
                pushIfNotIn(av.style, style);
                pushIfNotIn(av.size, size);
                pushIfNotIn(av.color, color);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return av;
}

console.log(getAvailability(undefined, 'M', undefined));
console.log(getAvailability('American Apparel', 'S', undefined));
console.log(getAvailability(undefined, 'M', 'black'));
console.log(getAvailability(undefined, 'M', 'green'));
console.log(getAvailability(undefined, undefined, 'green'));
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/uHAyirOX/1/edit

Obviously a more generic solution can be extrapolated from this method, with variable number of arguments and more levels in the availability object. Still, you have something to work it.

---

UPDATE: Generic solution (called in the same way)

```
function pushIfNotIn(arr, item) {
    if (!arr) arr = [];
    if (arr.indexOf(item) === -1) arr.push(item);
    return arr;
}

function getAvailability() {
  var result = [];  
  ~function getAvailabilityRecursive (level, availability, values) { 
    if (!values.length) return true;
    var isAvailable = false;
    var val = values[0];
    values = values.slice(1);
    for (var key in availability) {  
      if ((val === undefined || val === key) &&
          (getAvailabilityRecursive(level+1, availability[key], values))){
        result[level] = pushIfNotIn(result[level], key);
        isAvailable = true;        
      }
    }    
    return isAvailable;    
  }(0, availability, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));

  return result;  
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/uHAyirOX/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

Low-tech approach with the benefit of being immediately obvious for anyone maintaining it.

This could be an Ajax response, plain and simple:

```
var products = [
    { id: 101, style: 'aa', size: 's', colour: 'grey' },
    { id: 102, style: 'aa', size: 'm', colour: 'grey' },
    { id: 103, style: 'aa', size: 'l', colour: 'black' },
    /* ... 500 more ... */
    { id: 604, style: 'gi', size: 'l', colour: 'blue' }
];
```

Now just filter that array brute-force on the client side:

```
function Drilldown(items, properties) {
    var self = this,
        numItems = items.length,
        numProps = properties.length;

    self.setFilter = function (filterDef) {
        var i, item, p, prop, pass, filter = filterDef || {};

        self.items = [];
        self.properties = {};

        for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            pass = true;
            for (p = 0; pass && p < numProps; p++) {
                prop = properties[p];
                pass = pass && (!filter[prop] || filter[prop] === item[prop]);
                if (!self.properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    self.properties[prop] = {};
                }
                if (!self.properties[prop].hasOwnProperty(item[prop])) {
                    self.properties[prop][item[prop]] = [];
                }
            }
            if (pass) {
                self.items.push(item);
                for (p = 0; p < numProps; p++) {
                    prop = properties[p];
                    self.properties[prop][item[prop]].push(item);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    self.setFilter();
}
```

Usage:

```
var dd = new Drilldown(products, ['style', 'size', 'colour']);

dd.setFilter({size: 'l'});
/*
dd.items => [ array of size L products ]
dd.properties => {
    style: {
        aa: [ array of size L products in style 'aa' (1) ],
        gi: [ array of size L products in style 'gi' (1) ]
    },
    size: {
        s: [ array of size L products in size S (0) ],
        m: [ array of size L products in size M (0) ],
        l: [ array of size L products in size L (2) ]
    },
    colour: {
        grey:  [ array of size L products in Grey  (0) ],
        black: [ array of size L products in Black (1) ],
        blue:  [ array of size L products in Blue  (1) ]
    }
*/
```

`dd.properties` contains the all property combinations. Naturally some of the entries will be empty (array length 0), but all of them will be *there*. This makes indexing into this object straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have done something as:

```
var items = {

            'item1':{

                'level1' : {
                    'level2' : {},
                    'level2' : {'level3' :{}}
                },

                'level1' : {
                    'level2' : {},
                    'level2' : {'level3' :{}}
                }
            },

            'item2':{

                'level1' : {
                    'level2' : {},
                    'level2' : {'level3' :{}}
                },

                'level1' : {
                    'level2' : {},
                    'level2' : {'level3' :{}}
                }

            }
        }
```

That a first selector(Style, for example) can dictates availabilities for next(Colour) and so on.

In any level user can change only levels below.

Comment: We did an A/B test with this and if we force the users to follow a path style first, then size for example they're more likely to abandon their purchase than if they can start wherever they want. This is why I want them to choose whatever they want to start with and work from there.